# Visualizing the primes with the Riemann Zeta function

Tags: plotting, special-functions, complex, visualization, number-theory

I am trying to plot the identity seen [here](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/encoding2.htm), namely that if we define: 
$$\psi _{0}(x)={\frac  12}\left(\sum _{{n\leq x}}\Lambda (n)+\sum _{{n<x}}\Lambda (n)\right)$$
Then, it equal to the following, where the sum is taken over the nontrivial zeta zeroes.
$$\psi _{0}(x)=x-\sum _{{\rho }}{\frac  {x^{{\rho }}}{\rho }}-{\frac  {\zeta '(0)}{\zeta (0)}}-{\frac  {1}{2}}\log(1-x^{{-2}})$$
The linked website show a very nice graphic where $n$ is the number of zeta zeroes used to approximate the function:

[image]

However, I am having trouble reproducing this. My goal is just to plot this for one value of $n$. 
So, my exact definition of the function in question seems to be working fine:

```
    Ches0[x_] := 
 1/2 (Sum[MangoldtLambda[n], {n, 1, x}] + 
    Sum[MangoldtLambda[n], {n, 1, x - 1}])
```

However, my implementation of the approximate identity, while it gets the values at the jumps right, seems to be very off in most other respects.

```
Ches0Appr[x_] := 
 x - Log[2*Pi] - Sum[x^ZetaZero[i]/ZetaZero[i], {i, 1, 100}] - 
  1/2*Log[1 - 1/x^2]
```

I'm not exactly sure what's going wrong here, so my question is, how can I plot the second formula in my post?

Comment: [Related.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133340/visualizing-the-riemann-zeta-function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have implicitly mentioned, your implementation of the second formula omits the non-trivial zeros with negative imaginary part. When the sum is taken over **all** zeros, then the imaginary part of the sum cancels, leaving just a real part. For example,

```
Simplify[ComplexExpand[Re[x^(1/2 + I*t)/(1/2 + I*t) +
                          x^(1/2 - I*t)/(1/2 - I*t)]],
         Assumptions -> x >= 1]
```

The result involves only the real values `t` and `x`.

```
(4 Sqrt[x] (Cos[t Log[x]] + 2 t Sin[t Log[x]]))/(1 + 4 t^2)
```

If the `Psi[x,n]` function is defined as follows, the calculations using the code from @ubpdqn are much faster.

```
ChebyshevPsiZeta[x_Integer, n_Integer] :=
   Block[{t = N[Im[ZetaZero[Range[n]]]], tlogx},
      tlogx = t*Log[x];
      x - Log[2 Pi] - Log[1 - 1/x^2]/2 - 
      4 Sqrt[x] Total[ (Cos[tlogx] + 2 t Sin[tlogx])/(1 + 4 t^2)]]
```

Define `vis2` which includes `ChebyshevPsiZeta[x,n]` instead of `f[x,n]` in `vis` from @ubpdqn.

```
vis2[n_] := 
   Plot[{g[x], ChebyshevPsiZeta[x, n]}, {x, 1, 100},
        Exclusions -> None,
        PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}, Background -> Black, Frame -> True, 
        PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{"n=", n}], 20, White], ImageSize -> 400, 
        PlotRange -> {0, 100}]
```

Using `Map[vis2,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20,30,40,50}]` was about 25 times faster than with `vis`. Using `ParallelMap` was about 90 times faster.

Also note that the following definition of the von Mangoldt function by [Stefan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37007/von-mangoldt-function/37026#37026) is faster than the built-in `MangoldtLambda`.

```
vonMangoldtLambda[x_Integer] := If[Length[#]==1, Log[#[[1,1]]], 0]&[FactorInteger[x]]
SetAttributes[vonMangoldtLambda, Listable]
```

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT**

Based on useful J.M.'s comments: 
This is not efficient. However, it achieves result (I think):

```
f[x_, n_] := Module[{zero = Flatten[N[Table[ZetaZero[{j, -j}], {j, n}]]]}, 
x - Log[2 Pi] - Total[x^zero/zero] - Log[1 - 1/x^2]/2]
g[x_] := Sum[MangoldtLambda[j], {j, 1, Floor[x]}]

vis[n_] := 
 Plot[{g[x], f[x, n]}, {x, 1, 100}, Exclusions -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}, Background -> Black, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{"n=", n}], 20, White], ImageSize -> 400, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 100}]
```

After a 4 km (40 minute) walk the following allowed export of gif:

```
animation = 
  vis[#] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 
    80, 90, 100, 150, 200, 250};
```

[image]

Comment: `ZetaZero[]` allows for negative indices, corresponding to the conjugate of the corresponding positive index. Thus: `f[x_, n_] := Module[{zero = Flatten[N[Table[ZetaZero[{j, -j}], {j, n}]]]}, x - Log[2 Pi] - Total[x^zero/zero] - Log[1 - 1/x^2]/2]`.

Comment: @J.M. thank you. My ignorance. I will edit.